# Firebase RealTime Database - Security Rule

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I need your help with securing my Realtime Database. So I want to add security rule like  **.read: "$uid == auth.uid"** to my pet>name but I cannot get the reference of $uid from above. Any help? I just want to make my pet>name readable only for those whose $uid == auth.uid.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid == auth.uid",
          ".write": "$uid == auth.uid",
        "name": {
          ".read": "$uid == auth.uid",
            ".write": "$uid == auth.uid"
        }
      }
    },
    "pet": {
        "name":{
          ".read": "auth != null",
          ".write": false
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't reference wildcards outside of the tree where your rules are defined.  `$uid` under "users" references the name of the node being matched.  It's not a general purpose variable.

Comment: @DougStevenson What would be the proper solution, so I can get the reference of the wildcard?

Comment: I don't know.  What are you trying to accomplish?  Please edit the question to explain your goal.  It will be helptul to also show the code for the queries that you wish to allow or deny.

Comment: @DougStevenson I just want to make my pet>name readable only for those whose $uid == auth.uid.

Comment: That's not possible with your current structure, since you don't have a UID in the path of your pet data.  Put a UID in the path, create a wildcard for it (like you are with users), then use that in your rule.